# Alloy: a compact Java program to perform different run command scopes

Tags: java, scope, command, signature, alloy

Let say I am wanting to create a Java program to perform several Alloy runs, changing their scope values (integers from 0 to 9) for each loop, to check which is going to find a less time spent solution.

Have a note that the command is practically the same, I mean, only the values of the scope (and the presence/absence of the reserved word “exactly”) will vary.

Here is an numeric example:

```
1st run → command: run MyPred for 3 but 5 Int, exactly 1 Sig_Scope1, 1 Sig_Scope2, exactly 1 Sig_Scope3
2nd run → command: run MyPred for 4 but 5 Int, 2 Sig_Scope1, exactly 2 Sig_Scope2, exactly 2 Sig_Scope3
3rd run → command: run MyPred for 4 but 5 Int, 2 Sig_Scope1, exactly 1 Sig_Scope2, 1 Sig_Scope3
```

And so on, until a max number of iterations (suppose 10) has reached.

```
10th run → command: run MyPred for 4 but 5 Int, 0 Sig_Scope1, exactly 2 Sig_Scope2, 0 Sig_Scope3
```

A program output would be something like this:

```
1st run. Found solution: Yes. Spent time: 17 seconds
2nd run. Found solution: No. Spent time: [it may take a time until the Alloy analyzer is going to return no solution]
3nd run. Found solution: No. Spent time: [it may take a time until the Alloy analyzer is going to return no solution]
...
9th run. Found solution: Yes. Spent time: 21 seconds
10th run. Found solution: Yes. Spent time: 10 seconds
```

Here a pseudo code I am trying to go through, but there are a lot of pieces (text questions) I have no idea how to implement it or how can I find more study material:

```
...
A4Reporter rep = new A4Reporter() {...}
...
Module world = CompUtil.parseEverything_fromFile(rep, null, filename); //reading Alloy filename.
...
A4Options options = new A4Options(); //Analyzer’s options.
...
Command command: world.getAllCommands(); //I’am looking for Alloy’s ‘run’ commands, for instance, the first run command would be: run MyPred for 3 but 3 Int, exactly 1 Sig_Scope1, 1 Sig_Scope2, exactly 1 Sig_Scope3
...
Int max_number_of_runs = 10;
for(i = 0; i < max_number_of_runs; i++) {
    A4Solution ans = TranslateAlloyToKodkod.execute_command(rep, world.getAllReachableSigs(), command, options); //get all Signatures, fine :)
    System.out.println(ans); //printing the whole command.
    if (ans.satisfiable()) {
        //How can I get the amount of time (in seconds) to found a solution as an integer or String?
        //Getting the label of the Sigs. I have got this way, however I do not know if it is the right one.
        SafeList<Sig> sigs = ans.getAllReachableSigs();
            for (Sig sig : sigs) {
                System.out.println(sig.shortLabel());
            }
        //For each Sig how can I get their values?
        //How can I build a new command (Command new_built_command) for the next run? The values of scope Sig will come from a list or they will be generated through Java Random class (I mean a know how to generate random integers).
        command = new_built_command;
    } else {
        //A message that the current command did not find a solution as a String!
    }
}
```

Could you help me out on that, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I build a new command

You can see [ExampleUsingTheAPI](https://github.com/kaptoxic/alloy/blob/master/src/edu/mit/csail/sdg/alloy4whole/ExampleUsingTheAPI.java) for an example of using the Alloy API for constructing Alloy models.  Using that API you can programmatically construct a `Command` to run.  Alternatively, you can start with an Alloy model in a text form, parse it using [`CompUtil.parseEverything_fromString`](https://github.com/kaptoxic/alloy/blob/master/src/edu/mit/csail/sdg/alloy4compiler/parser/CompUtil.java), then do a string find-replace on the original Alloy model to update the command, and start all over again.

> For each Sig how can I get their values?

See [ExampleCompilingFromSource](https://github.com/kaptoxic/alloy/blob/master/src/edu/mit/csail/sdg/alloy4whole/ExampleCompilingFromSource.java), line 44.  Basically, once you get an `A4Solution` object, you can call the `eval` method on it to evaluate any expression against the found solution (if you pass a `Sig` object, you'll get its value in the solution).

> How can I get the amount of time (in seconds) to found a solution as an integer or String?

I'm not sure `A4Solution` contains any information about solving time, so in that case you'd have to measure time yourself.